# JavaFX Listview not updating when giving it an empty ArrayList

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm writing a project in MVC Format and it's supposed to become a music player.

In my View I have the Listview's library and playlist like this:

```
private ListView<ISong> library = new ListView<ISong>();
private ListView<ISong> playlist = new ListView<ISong>();

public ListView<ISong> getLibrary() {return library;}
public ListView<ISong> getPlaylist() {return playlist;}

public View() {
    HBox hBoxCenter = new HBox(library, playlist);
```

We also have the Classes "Playlist" and "Song" which both implement an Interface given to us, and "Playlist" has the following ArrayList, which starts out being completely empty:

```js
package model;

import interfaces.IPlaylist;
import interfaces.ISong;
import javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Playlist extends ModifiableObservableListBase<ISong> implements IPlaylist {
    private ArrayList<ISong> songs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean addSong(ISong s) throws RemoteException {
        if (songs.add(s)){
            return true;
        }
        throw new RemoteException("Song could not be added!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteSong(ISong s) throws RemoteException {
        if (songs.contains(s)){
            songs.remove(s);
            return true;
            }
        throw new RemoteException("Song does not exist in this Playlist!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteSongByID(long id) throws RemoteException {
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i ++){
            if (songs.get(i).getId() == id){
                songs.remove(i);
                return true;
            }
        }
        throw new RemoteException("No Song with matching ID exists in Playlist!");
    }

    @Override
    public void setList(ArrayList<ISong> s) throws RemoteException {
        if (s != null) {
            songs = s;
            return;
        }
        throw new RemoteException("Playlist can not be null.");
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<ISong> getList() throws RemoteException {
        try {
            return songs;
        }catch(Exception e){throw new RemoteException();}
    }


    @Override
    public void clearPlaylist() throws RemoteException {
        try {
            songs.clear();
        }catch(Exception e){throw new RemoteException();}
    }

    @Override
    public int sizeOfPlaylist() throws RemoteException {
        try {
            return songs.size();
        }catch(Exception e){throw new RemoteException();}
    }


    @Override
    public ISong findSongByPath(String name) throws RemoteException {
        for(int i=0; i<songs.size();i++){
            ISong song = songs.get(i);
            if (song.getPath().equals(name)) return song;
        }
        throw new RemoteException("Could not find song with given Path!");
    }

    @Override
    public ISong findSongByID(long id) throws RemoteException {
        for(int i=0; i<songs.size();i++){
            ISong song = songs.get(i);
            if (song.getId()==id) return song;
        }
        throw new RemoteException("Could not find song with given ID!");
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<ISong> iterator() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ISong get(int index) {
        return songs.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return songs.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAdd(int index, ISong element) {
        songs.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected ISong doSet(int index, ISong element) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected ISong doRemove(int index) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In my Controller I link them like this:

```
public void link (Model model, View view){
    this.view = view;
    this.model = model;
    view.getLibrary().setItems(model.getLibrary());
    view.getPlaylist().setItems(model.getPlaylist());
}
```

The MainClass looks as follows:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Model model = new Model();
    View view = new View();
    Controller controller = new Controller();

    controller.link(model,view);
    view.setController(controller);
    controller.initializePlaylist();

    Scene scene = new Scene(view);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    controller.cleanup();

}
```

**Now here comes my Problem:**
When the GUI opens and the ArrayList is empty, it won't show any further changes made to the ArrayList. HOWEVER, if I add an "empty" Song into my ArrayList and then simply clear the list after the GUI is open, everything works just fine (This is exactly the reason why I wrote the initializePlaylist and the cleanup methods).

Sorry if this is a stupid question or if I didn't provide enough code snippets, I'm just really out of ideas at this point and I've been searching for the cause of this for hours.

Comment: You appear to be implementing your own `ObservableList` by having `Playlist` extend `ModifiableObservableListBase`. Can you show your full implementation of this class? It's possible you failed to implement it correctly. Also, why have `Playlist` _be_ an `ObservableList` instead of it just _containing_ an `ObservableList`?

Comment: @Slaw Quite honestly I do not know why it is like this. I'm very new to working with Java and I feel like I don't understand half of this project, as it is a group project and there's lots of stuff I haven't even wrote. 

I edited the full class into the Question.

Comment: Okay, I looked it up on the exercise sheet.

Playlist.java is supposed to extend ModifieableObservableListBase<ISong>, so we can hand the ListBase as an Parameter to the setItems Method of ListView.

Comment: I find that requirement... strange. It seems more prudent for `Playlist` to have an `ObservableList<ISong>` as a _member_. Either way, you or a group member have definitely not implemented `ModifiableObservableListBase` correctly; no changes are ever fired. All the `IPlaylist` methods bypass the base implementation which handles firing these changes for you. See [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ModifiableObservableListBase.html).

Comment: implementing your own observableList is a bad idea - except for a very good reason: normally you use the FXCollections factory methods to create it. So either the exercise is crap or it is specifically about extending it - which is well over the head of newbies (and again implies that exercise is .. suboptimal ;).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I think I'll give up for today and try again tomorrow. Still have about a month to finish this. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer here.